# Fine Uploader for S3 server side CORS via ASP.NET usage

Tags: php, asp.net, amazon-s3, cors, fine-uploader

I am converting a working copy of the s3demo-cors.php example code, to ASP.NET.  I am trying to understand in which instances the CORS handling is required.  For example I see that the PHP code calls the handleCorsRequest() before attempting to delete an object.  Why would the server running the PHP code to delete an object on S3 require any CORS headers?  Or are those headers used by the client after the script is done running?  I perhaps am rusty on when and how exactly the CORS headers are required, but from what I understand they are for the client side JavaScript so it may deal directly with S3 from the browser, not so the server can talk to S3.  Additionally, for the delete object feature, what security measures are in place, so that requests coming in to delete objects on S3 are authenticated?  Perhaps I am missing where in the code a delete request is first authorized?  Is it because the client only knows the key values for object they have uploaded?  What is someone else downloads the file, and can see the key value, could they submit a request to delete the object?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your signature server or delete file handler server and uploader instance/page are hosted on the same origin, there is no need to worry about CORS.  If your endpoints that handle delete file requests and/or signature requests are on a different origin than the one hosting your upload page, then you will need to deal with CORS.

If you are working in a cross-origin environment, then you must acknowledge the cross-origin requests in your server response appropriately.

As far as authentication/security is concerned, that is your responsibility.  Your web app should already handle this.

Comment: We have the uploader page and the page handling the signatures/deletes/success all on the same domain and server, which I would then assume means we do not have to worry about CORS.  However when the client side code needs to communicate with S3, doesn't some type of CORS need to be used there?  We need to configure our S3 bucket to accept our domain yes?  Other than that, the Fine Uploader javascript handles the rest?  Thanks.